# Failed to create a BizTalkDBversion COM component installed with a BizTalk server not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2009

Whenever I refresh group hub I seem to be getting the following error

> Out of memory (System.Management)
>   **Additional Information**
>   Failed to create a BizTalkDBversion COM component installed with a BizTalk server. 
>   Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

[image]

The BizTalk server itself is ok on RAM memory usage, SQL server seems to be ok too as per our sql guy. And there is no record in the event logs so I am a bit lost here..

There are some "not enough storage is available" topics here but nothing that links to BizTalk server. The issue just suddenly appeared.

I am thinking this is a SQL server issue? I would appreciate any ideas on what is causing the issue and how to resolve this.

Comment: I have no idea what this is about but I guess you've checked disk space? and your SQL guy checked the sql server logs?

Comment: The only similar error I came across in my search is this one. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d9e1a186-1b7c-4d79-b2a9-e4559f441b79/biztalkdbversion-com-component?forum=biztalkgeneral   Which basically says to restart the the Windows Management Instrumentation service

Comment: Did you try a Repair on the BizTalk install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only similar error I came across in my search is this one. social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/… Which basically says to restart the the Windows Management Instrumentation service – Dijkgraaf Dec 30 '17

The above comment from Mr Dijkgraaf has solved our issue :)

> Recently another cause of this error is the July patch 2018 (possibly included on the August Rollup patch 2018 as well) please see Colin Dijkgraaf's post here
>   https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2018/07/19/microsoft-security-updates-cause-biztalk-admin-console-errors-an-internal-failure-occurred-for-unknown-reasons-winmgmt/